# Using logger.propagate or logger.disabled causes my fastapi application to hang. Why?

Tags: python, logging, uvicorn

When starting a local uvicorn server using FastAPI I am trying to disable uvicorn's logging using the below

```
logger = logging.getLogger('uvicorn.error')

logger.disabled = True
```

And

```
logger.propagate = False
```

When I try to launch my app with the below, it hangs. Why is this? Without `logger.disabled` or `logger.propagate` the app runs fine, when I include them, it never starts up!

```
uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5001
```

Does anyone have any advice?